# failed to get all processes ..win32 excepction , how to fix it?

Tags: c#, process, permissions, client-server, admin

im making a task manager application (server-client) .. so i get processors list from the server as a string. 
 my problem that 60-65% of processors count is failed to get in the server side as you see in the task manager snapshot .. note that server application debugged as **administrator**
Server code:

```
public void GetProcessors()
    {
        int i =0,j = 0;
        string answer = "";
        foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            try
            {
                answer += p.MainModule.ModuleName
                + "|" + p.Id.ToString()
                + "|" + string.Format("{0:N0} K", p.WorkingSet64 / 1024)
                + "|" + p.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription;
                i++;
                answer += "?";
            }
            catch 
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
        answer = answer.Remove(answer.Length - 1, 1);
        send(string.Format("get<{0}<{1}<{2}", answer, i, j));
    }
```

Client side:
this called the getProcessors method from task manager class

```
switch(command[1])
                    {
                        case "get":
                            Console.WriteLine(command[2]);
                            if (InvokeRequired)
                            {
                                Action a = () => taskManager1.GetProcessors(command[2], command[3], command[4]);
                                Invoke(a);
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                        break;
                    }
```

(client side) TASK MANAGER CLASS :

```
public void GetProcessors(string cmd,string success,string fail)
    {
        string[] Processors = cmd.Split('?');
        foreach (string process in Processors)
        {
            string[] info = process.Split('|');
            if (info.Length < 4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(info.Length.ToString());
                continue;
            }
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(info[0]);
            item.SubItems.Add(info[1]);
            item.SubItems.Add(info[2]);
            item.SubItems.Add(info[3]);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
        labelProcess.Text = string.Format("Processors: {0}", success);
        failedLabel.Text = string.Format("Failed: {0}", fail);
    }
```

[image]

i got those exception
85 FAILS : 83 are {"A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process."}
the other 2 FAILS : {"Unable to enumerate the process modules."}

after i edited the code and tried to run it without using Process.MainModule .. it gives me:
process : 147 .. FAIL : 0 .. so why i can't access to process.MainModule ?

## How do i fix that ??

Comment: Can you try and add `(Exception ex)` to the catch block: `catch {j++;}`?  What is the exception?

Comment: Processors and processes are very different things. The former is a piece of hardware. The latter is a program being executed.

Comment: i had like 86 of 88 FAILED
this exception message :{"A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process."}
and 2 of 88 FAILED 
this exception message :{"Unable to enumerate the process modules."}

Comment: yea i see.. but is there anyway that i can get the info i want?

Comment: when i changed the debugger mode to x64 it got
success 146 , fail 3
its a great result .. but now my program is for 64 bit .. i need my application to run on any pc .. Do i have to make two copies of my application ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i changed my application debugger to x64 it works .. but i think now i have to make two copies 32bit and 64bit 
 ...[image]

Comment: How can I change application debugger ? I use VS2012 x86, Win7 64bits.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is self-explanatory. You need to use Windows's 64-bit API, so you need to build a 64-bit version of your tool.

The second error is very mysterious. Some googling came up with «You won't be able to access the MainModule property for some processes (those running under SYSTEM credentials) or for the built-in "System" process.» It's an expected error.

Comment: true .. so now if i want my application to work on any pc .. i need to make two copies (x64, x86) right ??

Comment: You cannot enumerate modules of System Idle task or SYSTEM.

Comment: @Mur Haf Soz, If you want it to run on both types of systems, yes. But that's typically very easy to do.